# Android JavaFX Blendmode/Overlay effect

Tags: android, javafx-2

I'm new to android developing so forgive me if this is a dumb question but i was trying to make an app with some nice graphical effects where you have some transparent objects that show a background that's only visible through the objects so they act like "windows". A very nice example of this can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm). I would like to know if this kind of effect is possible in android? (I don't need to know about JavaFX I understand it there I just want to know how to achieve the same effect as shown on the site)

Thanks in advance, crognar.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, JavaFX 2 is not yet available on Android platform.